# Sqlsheet formula evaluation

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, excel-formula, scriptella

We use sqlsheet library to read data from a excel sheet. The lib works fine but there is a poblem with fields that are calculated by formulas. The values of that cells are always empty.

Is there a way to tell sqlsheet to evaluate the cell formulas before executing the data query?

Answer (score 1):

I decompiled the driver and within the XLSResultSet of the net.pcal.sqlsheet added in the following hssf cell check:

```
public static String getStrVal(Cell cell) {
    long ival = 0;
    Boolean bool = false;
    String cData = "";

        switch(cell.getCellType()){
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                cData = null;
                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                cData = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cData = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cData = String.valueOf(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                        break;

                }
                break;
            default:
                cData = "unsupported cell type";
                break;
        }
        return cData;
}
```

Then to the existing string check modified it so it is as follows:

```
public String getString(String jdbcColumn) throws SQLException {
    Cell cell = getCell(jdbcColumn);
    if (cell == null) {
        return cell == null ? null : formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    }else{
        String myCell = getStrVal(cell);
        return myCell;
    }
}
```

This resolved the issue for both formulas and for referenced cells.